# Can clotted cream be made with UHT cream?

Tags: cream, dairy, clotted-cream

I've followed a couple of recipes for clotted cream without success and it seems that pasteurization is the issue. I'm told that I need to use either unpasteurized cream or cream that has been low-temperature pasteurized.

All I can find here in Stockholm is cream pasteurized at higher temperatures (85 degrees C). Does anyone know why high temperature pasteurized cream doesn't work for clotted cream? Does anyone have a trick up their sleeve to get it to work?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/how-to-make-scalded-clotted-cream

Comment: All recipes I've seen call for raw milk, the pasteurisation messes up the clotting action. (see slightly related question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/what-is-the-effect-of-using-pasteurized-milk-in-cheese-making)

Comment: If you are referring to Stockholm Sweden, you probably misunderstand what UHT means. Typical Swedish (e.g. Arla brand) cream is pasteurized, but not UHT treated.

Comment: It appears that you are right, that this is not UHT. Yes it's Arla brand I have used. The cartons are marked "högpastöriserad" (high pasteurized). According to wikipedia the pasteurization is done at 85 degrees C.

Answer (score 3):

This [recipe](http://www.examiner.com/food-in-new-york/how-to-make-devonshire-cream) seems to suggest that using UHT cream will work, but that it will be a bit softer than if non-UHT cream is used.  Perhaps you can compare your technique to the one suggested in this recipe to see where it diverges.

Comment: A little further hunting and I found this article (http://www.notdelia.co.uk/confused-about-cream/ ), which perhaps explains some of the problem.  Clotted cream is made by slow heat treatment, but by definition, UHT cream has been treated with high heat, so this may have modified the structure in a way that interferes with getting the thickest clotted cream.